# Clear a TableView in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm in the process of learning how to display data and tables using PyQt. Ultimately I'd like to have a Table showing the contents of a database, but for now I'm just getting to grips with some of the fundamentals. I have a basic setup (pasted below) made using Qt Designer with a set of buttons ("Create", "Add Row", "Add Column", and "Clear"). "Create" makes a dummy table with pretend data. All of the buttons work apart from the "Clear" button, and when I click it, Python crashes entirely, and I'm left with no error messages to start working out what is wrong.

My questions are: 1) What am I doing wrong? 2) What can I do in the form of exception handling to prevent this, so I can see what's gone wrong in the future ?

```
import sys
from sqlite3 import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from test_class import Ui_MainWindow

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow, QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.createbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.file_dialog)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.addrowbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.add_row)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.addcollumnbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.add_column)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.clearbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.clear_table)

def add_row(self):
    self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow (0)       

def add_column(self):
    self.ui.tableWidget.insertColumn (0)

def clear_table(self):
    #This bit that won't seem to work in any combination!
    #self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()
    self.ui.tableWidget.clear()
    #self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
    #self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

def file_dialog(self):
    self.ui.textEdit.setText("Testing testing")
    self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
    a = QTableWidgetItem("A")
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem (0, a)
    a = QTableWidgetItem("B")
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem (1, a)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem (2, a)
    b = QTableWidgetItem("Test")
    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(1,1,b)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "crashes entirely"? Without stack trace and everything? Hard to believe...

Anyway, the PyQt4 documentation knows neither QTableView.clear nor QTableView.clearContents, but it knows [QTableView.clearSpans](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#clearSpans) which is supposed to do what you want.

Comment: Argh, I realised I'm using a tableWidget, not a tableView, my mistake! For the moment I've been working on tableWidget as I can't seem to find any working examples online of tableViews that actually run at all.

The weird behaviour I am experiencing is that windows simply says "python.exe has stopped working" and forces the program to quit. Is there anything else I could try to get it working with a tableWidget?

Comment: Actually, I have sorted it out with a QSql model, which was what I was after in the end anyway. Thanks for the help though, you pointed me in the right direction to finally get it sorted out!

Comment: Still weird... QTableWidget knows both `clear` and `clearContents` (the latter leaves the headers in place). But glad to hear something else works.

Comment: This answer does not suffice, as clearSpans() has no effect on the data in a QTableView

Comment: clearSpans does not remove the contents at all, how is this the chosen answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but:

1) What am I doing wrong?

- Any error can cause the crash, so I cannot answer.

2) What can I do in the form of exception handling to prevent this, so I can see what's gone wrong in the future ?

- Run python in debug mode. Under windows, the clean crash is the PyQT behaviour when any error happens.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475965/fastest-way-to-populate-qtableview-from-pandas-data-frame/31557937?noredirect=1#comment69470093_31557937) question should get you going with QTableView objects.